# How do I find the repeatable or 'evergreen' PFS scenarios?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

How do I find the official repeatable ('evergreen' or 'replayable') scenarios of the Pathfinder Society (First or Second edition)? Society rules only permit a player to repeat officially repeatable scenarios for credit; the vast majority cannot be replayed for credit.

Comment: Related meta on topicality: ["Find Me a Resource."](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4987/4398)

Comment: I've edited the question to include both editions, as this is mainly about PFS having the current edition in the question makes sense, however removing PF-1e invalidates original answers. Therefore we should just expand the scope given the expanded scope of PFS.

Answer (score 3):

### Check on the Paizo Store.

One of the sections in the Paizo online store is the [Replayable Scenarios](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/pfsScenarios/replayableScenarios) section.  This has all of the currently-purchasable Tier 1-2 scenarios that Paizo sells.  It's not a complete list on it's own, but it is certainly authoritative.  To find the others...

### Ask on the Paizo forums.

I hate giving an answer like this, but after an hour of searching online I'm pretty confident in saying that there are no easily-accessible lists of Pathfinder Society adventures outside of the Paizo store.  According to [this thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2tjla?Tier-1-replayability) from March 2016, there are several adventures that count as evergreen that I can't find on the Paizo store.  Since the list of applicable scenarios is going to change season-to-season, in this case the quickest way to get a pretty good list of evergreen adventures would be to ask on the general Pathfinder Society [forums](http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/paizoPublishing/pathfinder/pathfinderSociety/general).

### Check yourself.

As a final option, it's also possible for you to check if a particular adventure is evergreen yourself.  The rule for what counts as evergreen is pretty simple:

> All Tier 1 and 1-2 adventures can be replayed an unlimited
>   number of times with a 1st-level character for credit.

So, if you have an adventure that's either Tier 1 or Tier 1-2 and is playable in the current season, then that adventure is evergreen.

Comment: No Replayable Scenarios section now exists on the Paizo site.

Answer (score 1):

Repeatable scenarios, Pathfinder 2e, Pathfinder Society

All scenarios of Pathfinder 1st Ed., Pathfinder 2d Ed., and Starfinder may be found at https://www.pfstracker.net/

As of this date (2022-07-13), these are the Pathfinder Society (2d edition) scenarios listed as repeatable on the [Pathfinder Wiki site](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/).

1-01, 1-06, 1-10, 1-14, 1-23
2-06, 2-11
3-01, 3-13
4-01

Source:
Season 1 https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Year_of_the_Open_Road
Season 2 https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Year_of_Corruption%27s_Reach
Season 3 https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Year_of_Shattered_Sanctuaries
Season 4 https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Year_of_Boundless_Wonder